# Excel/VBA/Application.OnTime

Tags: excel, vba

I have zero programming experience (of any sort, so please speak slowly if you ARE able to help me :-)), but have managed (with the help of these forums) to kludge together the following (I'm sure you'd all ROFL if you saw some of the others).

```
Sub StartTimer()
RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 1, 0)
Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, procedure:=cRunWhat, schedule:=True
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:59:03"), "StartTimer"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:40:00"), "Macro1"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:45:00"), "Macro2"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:11:00"), "StopTimer"
End Sub
```

The macro associated with "StartTimer" (cRunWhat) runs as it should.
Macro1 and Macro2 don't run (although both run if started manually - there are no issues with Macro1 and Macro2 on a stand alone basis).

I am guessing it is because the "timer" is already running when "TimeValue" gets to 13:40 and 13:45.

Do I have to stop the timer just before 13:40 to allow these macros to run (and then restart it afterwards), or is there another way of doing so without pausing the "StartTimer" macro?

Remember....please speak slowly  :-)

Thanks in anticipation

Hendrix

Comment: Does the StartTimer code loop continuously, is it repeatedly reschedule via `Application.OnTime`,  and/or does it contain `DoEvents` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Excel stacks scheduled ontime macros and executes them in the order of time or (if time is equal) in the orde rin which they were scheduled. As far as I know, there is no significant limit to the number of ontime macros you can schedule. So my guess is that there is another reason why Macro1 and Macro2 are not called. Perhaps your VBA project contains more than one "Macro1" subroutine?

Comment: Thanks jkpieterse.

Macro1 is actually not called Macro1 (I just called it this for the purposes of this question) - it has its own unique name.

Because "StartTimer" (which calls a forced recalculation routine of a specific range) is on a loop, I was wondering if this "locked out" the call of "Macro1".

I should have included the code for this too. My apologies:

    `Public RunWhen As Double
    Public Const cRunWhat = "CalculateRange"`

    and `Sub CalculateRange()
    Worksheets("Real Time Bars").Range("_HILO").Calculate
    Call StartTimer
    End Sub`

Comment: I see no obvious reason why the scheduled macros wouldn't run.